# WPF autocompletebox and the enter key

Tags: wpf, autocomplete

I am trying to get the WPF AutoCompleteBox to raise the KeyDown event when I press the enter key.  I am using the normal KeyDown hook, which works for everything but the enter key it seems.  Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: What do you want it to do when you press the Enter key?

Comment: ?? I want it to catch the event!

Comment: I ask about the use case because the Enter key already used by this control for selecting an item from the suggestions. The control captures the event and marks it as handled.

Comment: Have you figured any neater way to do this? I'm stuck on the same problem.

Comment: @Phonon: The answer listed below is pretty much the only way to go.  I wound up starting with that, then eventually writing a similar control from scratch. (AutoCompleteBox wasn't quite right for my purposes)  Subclassing it will work though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could inherit the `AutoCompleteBox`, adding an event for <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
public class MyAutoCompleteBox : AutoCompleteBox
{
    public override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
        if(e.Key == Key.Enter) RaiseEnterKeyDownEvent();
    }

    public event Action<object> EnterKeyDown;
    private void RaiseEnterKeyDownEvent()
    {
        var handler = EnterKeyDown;
        if(handler != null) handler(this);
    }
}
```

In your consuming class, you can subscribe:

```
public void Subscribe()
{
    autoCompleteBox.EnterKeyDown += DoSomethingWhenEnterPressed;
}

public void DoSomethingWhenEnterPressed(object sender)
{

}
```

Comment: Well it is a pain, but I guess it works.  Wish there was an easier way.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 9):

Very late answer, but I faced this same problem that brought me to this question and finally solved it using [PreviewKeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.previewkeydown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
<wpftoolkit:AutoCompleteBox Name="AutoCompleteBoxCardName"  
     Populating="LoadAutocomplete"  
     PreviewKeyDown="AutoCompleteBoxName_PreviewKeyDown"/>
```

and

```
private void AutoCompleteBoxName_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Good call.  I eventually solved my problem, and others that popped up by writing my own autocomplete box control.

Answer (score 4):

There *is* a slightly easier (and in my opinion more MVVM) way:

```
// This still goes in your code behind (yuck!)
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsDropDownOpen && SelectedItem != null && (e.Key == Key.Enter || e.Key == Key.Return))
            {
               // Drop down is closed so the item in the textbox should be submitted with a press of the Enter key
                base.OnKeyDown(e); // This has to happen before we mark Handled = false
                e.Handled = false; // Set Handled = false so the event bubbles up to your inputbindings
                return;
            }

            // Drop down is open so user must be selecting an AutoComplete list item
            base.OnKeyDown(e);
        }
```

This minimizes the blasphemous code-behind and allows your key event to continue to bubble up to something like an input binding:

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Tab" Command="{Binding NextCommand}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="Tab" Modifiers="Shift" Command="{Binding LastCommand}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="Escape" Command="{Binding ClearCommand}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding EnterCommand}"/>
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```

Comment: This would be a lovely solution, if only key bindings for `Enter` or `Return` worked reliably. But it seems that depending on the `AutoCompleteBox`s configuration, these are ignored.

Answer (score 2):

(I know this is a late answer, but I still think it's usefull for people who want to solve this issue, **without code behind**)

A good way to do this in **MVVM**

First add the reference:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

and from the NuGet package (MVVMLight):

```
xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras"
```

Than in your **View**:

```
<wpftoolkit:AutoCompleteBox Name="AutoCompleteBoxName">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewKeyDown">
                        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding AutoCompleteEnter}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</wpftoolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
```

and than in your **ViewModel** :

```
public ICommand AutoCompleteEnter { get { return new RelayCommand<System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs>(Auto_Complete_Enter); } }

public void Auto_Complete_Enter(System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //Detect if key is 'Enter/Return' key
    if ((e.Key == Key.Enter) || (e.Key == Key.Return))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("U have pressed the enter key");
    }
}
```

Hope this will still help some people out.

Comment: This is the way!

Answer (score 0):

So, I've spend a lot of time trying to get this thing to work. Other responses are certainly helpful and will get you to destination, but i have following issues with implementation:

1. I needed MVVM solution with an ability to bind Enter to Command within ViewModel, which means that Event Handlers was undesirable option.
2. I was trying to avoid adding additional dependencies to fix single event in a single control, so no MVVMLight.

Solution:

1. Pull copy of DonNetProjects.Input.Toolkit from [github](https://github.com/dotnetprojects/WpfToolkit)
2. Navigate to AutoCompleteBox/System/Windows/Controls/AutoCompleteBox.cs
3. Change overload of OnKeyDown method to following:

   ```
       if (IsDropDownOpen)
       {
           if (SelectionAdapter != null)
           {
               SelectionAdapter.HandleKeyDown(e);
               if (e.Handled)
               {
                   return;
               }
           }

           if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
           {
               OnAdapterSelectionCanceled(this, new RoutedEventArgs());
               //e.Handled = true;
           }
       }
       else
       {
           // The drop down is not open, the Down key will toggle it open.
           if (e.Key == Key.Down)
           {
               IsDropDownOpen = true;
               //e.Handled = true;
           }
       }

       // Standard drop down navigation
       switch (e.Key)
       {
           case Key.F4:
               IsDropDownOpen = !IsDropDownOpen;
               e.Handled = true;
               break;

           case Key.Enter:
               if (IsDropDownOpen)
               {
                   OnAdapterSelectionComplete(this, new RoutedEventArgs());
                   e.Handled = true;
               }
               break;

           default:
               break;
       }

       base.OnKeyDown(e);
   ```
4. Recompile to new DLL and reference it instead of original WPFToolkit.

Result:
If new version used as following:

```
   xmlns:tk="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=DotNetProjects.Input.Toolkit"
   <tk:AutoCompleteBox ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableValues}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <tk:AutoCompleteBox.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding AddValue}"/>
            </tk:AutoCompleteBox.InputBindings>
    </tk:AutoCompleteBox>
```

Resulting behavior is: if dropdown is open, Enter would be rerouted to it to complete selection, if dropdown is closed it will fire command in KeyBinding.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, when using [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/), you can simply use:

```
<Controls:AutoCompleteBox ItemsSource="{Binding Keywords}"
                          ValueMemberPath="Name"                   
                          Text="{Binding EnteredText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          IsTextCompletionEnabled="True"
                          cal:Message.Attach="[Event PreviewKeyDown] = [Action AddTagOnEnter($eventArgs)]" />
```

Specifically, note the last line to attach your event. For some other method parameter options, see [here](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Cheat%20Sheet).

Finally, define a public method in your ViewModel:

```
public void AddTagOnEnter(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key != Key.Enter) return;
    // Do something useful
}
```