# Command for WPF TextBox that fires up when we hit Enter Key

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, icommand

It is very easy to bind `Button`s in WPF apps to `Command`s in a `VIEWMODEL` class. I'd like to achieve a similar binding for a `TextBox`.

I have a `TextBox` and I need to bind it to a `Command` that fires up when I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> while the `TextBox` is focused. Currently, I'm using the following handler for the `KeyUp` event, but it looks ugly...
and I can't put it in my `VIEWMODEL` class.

```
private void TextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Enter)
    {
        // your event handler here
        e.Handled = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Enter Key is pressed!");
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Aryan, not every WPF object supports commanding. So if you wan't to do that you'll need either to call your view model from your code behind (a little coupled) or use some MVVM Messaging implementation to decouple that. See [MVVM Light Messaging toolkit](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/) for an example. Or simple use triggers like this:

```
<TextBox>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyUp">
            <i:InvokeDataCommand Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Ok thank you so much for replying....but this command will fires up on each key up event or just a ENTER key up event??

Comment: Every time. If you wan't just for the enter then you'll have to write a markup extension to do that, like this one: http://tomlev2.wordpress.com/2009/03/17/wpf-using-inputbindings-with-the-mvvm-pattern/

Comment: See this is the nice example i have found over [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/170895/InputBinding-for-WPF-and-Silverlight-with-MVVM)

Comment: Thanks. Current event trigger is  <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding QuickSearchTextKeyUp}"/>

Comment: how to apply this trigger on multiple textboxes

Answer (score 256):

I've faced with the same problem and found solution [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/437cff55-2af5-4878-ab85-6fb3bbd636c4), here is the code sample:

```
<TextBox>
  <TextBox.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=CmdSomething}" Key="Enter" />
  </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: NB you may need to set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on your TextBox binding for this to work.

Comment: that's stupid easy. except it doesn't work for AutoCompleteBox from the WPF Toolkit - for that see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996731

Comment: Richard Dingwall tell the terrible truth. what we need is 2 things: (1) Button.IsDefault="True"    (2) TextBox Text Binding add "UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged ". nothing more. even sarh's answer not to be used.

Comment: @HaiyuanLi: `Button.IsDefault` doesn't help much, if *each* textbox is to trigger a different button and/or bound command.

Comment: This doesn't work at all. 'UpdateSourceTrigger' is set to 'PropertyChanged'. I use the same command for a button in the same grid but the textbox doesn't trigger it.

Comment: Greate, just set Mode=TwoWay, pdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged <TextBox
                Text="{Binding Stages_Title, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <TextBox.InputBindings>
                    <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding RunInsertCommand}" />
                </TextBox.InputBindings>
            </TextBox>

Comment: this will work just fine without any of those additives unless you expect the contents of the box to change... then you need `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`

Answer (score 19):

I like Sarh's answer, but it wouldn't work in my program, unless I changed `Enter` to `Return`:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Return" Command="{}" />
   </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: I made the same experience

Answer (score 7):

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding FieldThatIAmBindingToo, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding AddCommand}" Key="Return" />
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

I took answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413927/executing-viewmodels-command-on-enter-in-textbox/21110210#21110210)

Answer (score -9):

You can set true to AcceptReturn property.

```
 <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" />
```

Comment: All this does is allow the textbox to be multiline and handle the keypress itself, rather than triggering the default button action.