# MessageBox doesn't take focus

Tags: c#, wpf, focus, messagebox, keyup

When I click enter-button, `MessageBox` is shown. I want `MessageBox` to close when I click enter-button again as usual. Problem is - it doesn't have focus, but `TextBox` has and when I click enter-button `_textBox_OnKeyUp` eventhandler is invoked again and again. How can I solve my problem?

**Markup:**

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Name="_textBox"
        Width="100"
        Height="30"
        Background="OrangeRed"
        KeyUp="_textBox_OnKeyUp"/>
</Grid>
```

**Code:**

```
private void _textBox_OnKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key != Key.Enter)
        return;

    MessageBox.Show("Bla-bla");
}
```

Comment: show this, I think, it is same with your case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882196/wpf-command-for-textbox-which-fires-up-when-we-hit-enter-key-on-it

Comment: It is one of the infamous airspace issues, activation and focus needs to be emulated in WPF because controls are not windows.  That can be quite glitchy if you don't do it the "normal" way, WPF has a hard-baked assumption that shortcut keystrokes are implemented with the KeyDown notification.  Using that event instead trivially solves your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`KeyDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx) event instead because the `MessageBox` responds to the `KeyDown` event:

```
<TextBox Name="_textBox"
         Width="100"
         Height="30"
         Background="OrangeRed"
         KeyDown="_textBox_OnKeyDown"/>
```

And:

```
private void _textBox_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key != Key.Enter)
       return;

    MessageBox.Show("Bla-bla");
}
```

Comment: Thx, it seems to work, but what can I do if I MUST use KeyUp event?

Answer (score 1):

I recomend using [this method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598678.aspx) of Messagebox.

```
MessageBox.Show(Window, String)
```

Taken from the MSDN :

> Displays a message box in front of the specified window. The message
>   box displays a message and returns a result.

You can use this as the following :

```
MessageBox.Show(Application.Current.MainWindow, "I'm on top of teh window so I should get focus");
```

EDIT :

You should give back the focus to your main window before calling the MessageBox.

```
private void _textBox_OnKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key != Key.Enter)
        return;

    //this.Focus() or at least YourWindow.Focus()
    MessageBox.Show("Bla-bla");
}
```

Comment: No this doesn't still close the `MessageBox` by clicking the enter button again as OP wanted.

Comment: Agree with Akbai and in real application (not in this test) I have Application.Current.MainWindow = null

Comment: I've made an edit, if your Application.Current.MainWindow is null then you should replace my commentary by something that gives you the current window

Comment: I just used 'this' since I'm already in the Form needed to be ontop

    MessageBox.Show(this, ....)